# sleep method doesn't working if i call second time?

Tags: multithreading, time, draw, sleep, geometry

Here i am actually trying to do a simple animation. A circle will getting smaller and smaller with a particular speed. I used sleep method to set interval between each time of reducing the radius of the circle.  I gave five seconds for sleep method. But the problem is , it is working for first 5 seconds after launching the app and it is not working second time. It is reducing faster after 5 seconds.

I want to reduce the radius of the circle in particular interval of time. Please tell me how can i implement my idea in my code. Also tell me what mistake i did in my code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {
    int radius=100;

 boolean freeTouched = false;
 Path freePath;

 public MyView(Context context) {
  super(context);
 }

 public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
 }

 public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
 }
 Thread th=new Thread()
 {    
     public void run()
 {
     for(int i=100;i>0;i-=2){
         radius=i;
         try {
            sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         invalidate();
     }
     }
 };
 public void calThread(){

     Thread th=new Thread(){
         public void run(){
             try {
                sleep(5000); radius-=1; Log.i("kbt","inside thread 800 seconds");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
     };th.start();
    invalidate();
     Log.i("kbt", "Inside thread");
 }





@Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  super.onDraw(canvas);//th.start();
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
  canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, radius, paint);
 calThread();
 Log.i("kbt", "Inside clled");

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

  switch(event.getAction()){
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
   freeTouched = false;
   break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

     freeTouched = true;
    freePath = new Path();
    freePath.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY()); 

    break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
   freePath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
   invalidate();
   break;
  }

  return true;
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `calThread()` method gets called **repeatedly** before your `sleep()` method calling.

Since you repeatedly calling your `calThread()`method, it is not allowing you to access any one the code below it.

**Move** the function call below or at the **end** and then you can able to call `sleep()` function.